# How do I make wthe window borders have a transparent look to them in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: gnome, 18.10, transparency

I've seen that people have asked the same question, but they are all from the 12.04 era. What I want is to make the window borders have a transparency to them, like the top bar when no app is in full screen. Any help would be appriciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an appropriate theme

Themes allow you to customize almost anything on GNOME

As an example, see https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Transparent+Atolm?content=142932

Of course, there are many other options. You will have to decide for yourself